# How to set checkbox always checked when user redirect to another page?

Tags: asp.net, redirect, checkbox, code-behind

How do I implement my checkbox to stay check as it is even if user redirects to another page? Example, in my code behind when I check the checkbox the system updates the database and it says "Validated" , but when I press GoBackTeacher_Click event it will redirect to another page. In that another page there is a button function there that will redirect to this current page where my code behind function is implemented and checkbox is checked.

Aspx Code:

```
<div class="container" style="text-align: center; margin: 0 auto;">
    <br />
    <h1>Validation of Subjects</h1>
    <br />
    <asp:GridView runat="server" CssClass="table table-hover table-bordered" ID="ValidateSubject" Style="text-align: center"></asp:GridView>
</div>

<div style="float: right; padding-right: 75px;">
    <button type="button" runat="server" class="btn btn-success" onserverclick="GoBackTeacher_Click">Go Back</button>
</div>
```

Code Behind:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;

namespace SoftwareAnalysisAndDesign.SAD
{
    public partial class ValidateSubjectTeacher : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        CheckBox check = new CheckBox();
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (Session["ValidateSubject"] == null)
            {
                Response.Redirect("TeacherPage.aspx", true);
            }

            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                ValidateSubject.DataSource = Session["ValidateSubject"];
                ValidateSubject.DataBind();
            }
            //Add a checkbox in the last row of GridView Progmatically
            foreach (GridViewRow row in ValidateSubject.Rows)
            {
                check = row.Cells[row.Cells.Count - 1].Controls[0] as CheckBox; //position Check column on last row in gridview
                check.Enabled = true;
                check.CheckedChanged += ValidateSubject_Click; //Bind the event on the button
                check.AutoPostBack = true; //Set the AutoPostBack property to true
            }
        }
        protected void ValidateSubject_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            CheckBox chk = (CheckBox)sender;
            GridViewRow grvRow = (GridViewRow)chk.NamingContainer;//This will give row

            string validated = "Validated";
            string notyetvalidated = "Not yet validated";
            string studid = grvRow.Cells[0].Text;
            string coursenum = grvRow.Cells[1].Text;

            if (chk.Checked)
            {
                grvRow.Cells[10].Text = validated;
                //Open Connection
                using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=Keith;Initial Catalog=SAD;Integrated Security=True"))
                {
                    //Open Connection to database
                    try
                    {
                        conn.Open();
                    }
                    catch (Exception E)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(E.ToString());
                    }

                    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Update AssessmentForm set Status = @Validated where StudentID = @studentID and CourseNo = @Coursenumber" ,conn))
                    {
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Validated", validated);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@studentID", studid);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Coursenumber", coursenum);
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }

                    //Close Connection to database
                    try
                    {
                        conn.Close();
                    }
                    catch (Exception E)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(E.ToString());
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                grvRow.Cells[10].Text = notyetvalidated;
                //Open Connection
                using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=Keith;Initial Catalog=SAD;Integrated Security=True"))
                {
                    //Open Connection to database
                    try
                    {
                        conn.Open();
                    }
                    catch (Exception E)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(E.ToString());
                    }
                    //query database to update the Status
                    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Update AssessmentForm set Status = @Validated where StudentID = @studentID and CourseNo = @Coursenumber", conn))
                    {
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Validated", notyetvalidated);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@studentID", studid);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Coursenumber", coursenum);
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }

                    //Close Connection to database
                    try
                    {
                        conn.Close();
                    }
                    catch (Exception E)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(E.ToString());
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        protected void GoBackTeacher_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Response.Redirect("TeacherPage.aspx");
        }
    }
}
```

To further understand my question, here is an image to further explain it.

This is when I check the checkbox without pressing the go back button

[image]

And this where I go pressed the go back button and in the another page there is a proceed button to redirect to this current page where my gridview is located.

[image]

There the checkbox is unchecked, and the status says it is validated. How do I implement my code that checkbox stay checked?

Is it something to do with postback? Please help.

**UPDATE**

I've tried this, it will stay checked my redirecting to this page, but when checkbox is clicked the status will not change from "Validated" to "Not yet validated" it will not change on postback when clicked.

```
        foreach (GridViewRow row in ValidateSubject.Rows)
        {
            bool isChecked = default(bool);
            if (row.Cells[row.Cells.Count - 2].Text.Equals("Validated")) // Here please assign the position of **Status** column.
            {
                isChecked = true;
                check = row.Cells[row.Cells.Count - 1].Controls[0] as CheckBox; //position Check column on last row in gridview
                check.Enabled = true;
                check.CheckedChanged += ValidateSubject_Click; //Bind the event on the button
                check.AutoPostBack = true; //Set the AutoPostBack property to true
                check.Checked = isChecked; //Set checkbox checked based on status ;
            }
            else if (row.Cells[row.Cells.Count - 2].Text.Equals("Not yet validated"))
            {
                isChecked = false;
                check = row.Cells[row.Cells.Count - 1].Controls[0] as CheckBox; //position Check column on last row in gridview
                check.Enabled = true;
                check.CheckedChanged += ValidateSubject_Click; //Bind the event on the button
                check.AutoPostBack = true; //Set the AutoPostBack property to true
                check.Checked = isChecked; //Set checkbox checked based on status ;
            }
        }
```

In this function, the condition above will not changed the database, instead it will only refresh the page when checkbox is clicked.

```
protected void ValidateSubject_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            CheckBox chk = (CheckBox)sender;
            GridViewRow grvRow = (GridViewRow)chk.NamingContainer;//This will give row

            string validated = "Validated";
            string notyetvalidated = "Not yet validated";
            string studid = grvRow.Cells[0].Text;
            string coursenum = grvRow.Cells[1].Text;

            if (chk.Checked)
            {
                grvRow.Cells[10].Text = validated;
                //Open Connection
                using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=Keith;Initial Catalog=SAD;Integrated Security=True"))
                {
                    //Open Connection to database
                    try
                    {
                        conn.Open();
                    }
                    catch (Exception E)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(E.ToString());
                    }

                    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Update AssessmentForm set Status = @Validated where StudentID = @studentID and CourseNo = @Coursenumber" ,conn))
                    {
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Validated", validated);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@studentID", studid);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Coursenumber", coursenum);
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }

                    //Close Connection to database
                    try
                    {
                        conn.Close();
                    }
                    catch (Exception E)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(E.ToString());
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                grvRow.Cells[10].Text = notyetvalidated;
                //Open Connection
                using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=Keith;Initial Catalog=SAD;Integrated Security=True"))
                {
                    //Open Connection to database
                    try
                    {
                        conn.Open();
                    }
                    catch (Exception E)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(E.ToString());
                    }
                    //query database to update the Status
                    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Update AssessmentForm set Status = @Validated where StudentID = @studentID and CourseNo = @Coursenumber", conn))
                    {
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Validated", notyetvalidated);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@studentID", studid);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Coursenumber", coursenum);
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }

                    //Close Connection to database
                    try
                    {
                        conn.Close();
                    }
                    catch (Exception E)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(E.ToString());
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: The **Status** header having column values as **validated**  and **Not yet..**. Here you are changing the bit in database, So at the time to binding you can set checked to **true** or false **false** based on status bit.

Comment: Please share Gridview markup too that would be more helpful.

Comment: My gridview is auto generated columns sir so I get all the data and bind it into datatable. Could you provide a sample code sir to show how it is done?

Comment: Didn't it worked? Still having issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to modify your **Page_Load** method in the section where you are iterating inside gridview rows and assigning handlers and setting checkbox property.

In gridview the status column I guess you are saving it at text not a bit so I compared it as text. See following and implement same.

```
foreach (GridViewRow row in ValidateSubject.Rows)
 {
     bool isChecked = default(bool);
     if (row.Cells[row.Cells.Count - 1].Text.Equals("Validated")) // Here please assign the position of **Status** column.
          isChecked = true;
     check = row.Cells[row.Cells.Count - 1].Controls[0] as CheckBox; //position Check column on last row in gridview
     check.Enabled = true;
     check.CheckedChanged += ValidateSubject_Click; //Bind the event on the button
     check.AutoPostBack = true; //Set the AutoPostBack property to true
     check.Checked = isChecked //Set checkbox checked based on status ;
 }
```

Comment: The code prompts me with an error sir, An exception of type 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException' occurred in System.Web.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.

Sorry I'm quite new to this, where do I assign the position of the status?

Comment: Yeah, It will I have mentioned in a comment that in `Cells[]` you need to add the index of column named **Status**. Since i don'e know the position therefore you have to do it yourself e.g `row.Cells.Count - 1` or `row.Cells.Count -2` likewise.

Comment: `row.Cells[<Add Position Here>].Text.Equals("Validated")`. See my updated answer.

Comment: sir this is my code for this `row.Cells[row.Cells.Count - 8].Text.Equals("Validated")` since my status is in 8th row, is this correct?

Comment: 8th Row or in 8th column ?

Comment: in the above picture sir my status is in 11th column I mean, does the counter starts at 0 in the first column? let's say my status is in the 11th column so I have to declare my code like this? `row.Cells[row.Cells.Count - 2].Text.Equals("validated")` ??

Comment: Since you have programmatically added a column after binding the gridview so `row.Cells.Count - 1` need to be used keeping in mind that gridview index starts from 0 otherwise you can use `row.Cells.Count - 2` if former doesn't work.

Comment: Sir, I've updated my code above, it seems working but when I click again the status will not change instead it will only refresh the page. I need to update my status when checkbox is clicked from `"Not yet validated"` to `"Validated"` and vise versa. How do I do that?

Comment: OK, I have seen your updated code everything seem fine except for few thing, firstly as soon as you **check/uncheck** checkbox you are executing an `ValidateSubject_Click` event now here you do a post-back and change the status in database but after successful update you ain't rebinding the gridview with newer data. This is cause why changes aren't reflected as per my observation.

Comment: Secondly, wrap up all `foreach (GridViewRow row in ValidateSubject.Rows) { }` this section inside `!IsPostback` as these events have already been attached in normal load. Third and the last if your main target is just to change status and do nothing else don't perform any postback kind of activity just use an *$.ajax()* method to asynchronously update the data in database.